# navigator.device UNDEFINED in PHONEGAP - CORDOVA

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile, phonegap-build

I am using `PHONEGAP` - `CORDOVA`.
Why do I get this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'capture' of undefined

at this line:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureImage();
```

The project only imports `cordova.js` and `index.js`.  I am just trying to open `gallery` on android with a simple button.

Should I import another file to this project?

Thanks!

Comment: You should at least read the number point in bold. FAQ: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) There is not enough detail for me to tell you what is wrong. But index.js is NOT required. It is in many example as *nudge* to get programmers to write Javascript in a separate file. This alone tells me you are making too big of a jump for someone new to Cordova/Phonegap. The comment will tell you what you need.

Comment: 1) a 'deviceready' listener #4 in FAQ, 2) you should realize you are working with 3 different frameworks - don't get them mixed up. #1 in FAQ, 3) make sure you read the **correct** documentation. #2 in FAQ. 4) don't forget to add the plugin, if needed #8 in FAQ - 5) make sure your example code is appropriate for your system #9 in FAQ. 6) make sure you get the correct plugin #11 in FAQ.  -- Best of Luck

Comment: Almost forgot, `navigator.device` is for the HTML5 API, not phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you will need to add the Cordova media-capture plugin to your project as documented [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html).